# RegEx to remove lines from MySQL dump

Tags: regex, bash, sed

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

How can I remove FULLTEXT line from MySQL dump above and comma on the line before so it looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The removal should be easy using `sed` but I'm not sure how to remove this comma on the line above so the dump is successfully imported:

```
sed -i '/FULLTEXT KEY.*/d' dump.sql
```

Sometimes there is also more columns with FULLTEXT index:

```
CREATE TABLE `entity` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `company_name` (`company_name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: When you say "columns" above ITYM "rows".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sed script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
sed -e '/FULLTEXT/d' |    
sed -ne '
/ENGINE=InnoDB/!{H}
/ENGINE=InnoDB/{x; s/,[ \t]*$//; p; }
${g;p;}
'
```

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `entity` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `company_name` (`company_name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Sample Run:

```
/home/user> ./1.sed < input

CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `entity` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: That is not a sed script. It's a shell script calling sed multiple times and it will fail with different input since it's not removing the comma from the line before FULLTEXT, it's removing the FULLTEXT line and then performing magical incantations whether FULLTEXT had appeared in the input or not and only when the text ENGINE=InnoDB appears on the subsequent line.

Answer (score 2):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should use awk for clarity, brevity, portability, efficiency, robustness and most other desirable qualities of software. All of the sed constructs to do anything other than s, g, and p (with -n) became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented and exist today just for mental exercise.

Given this input:

```
$ cat file
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `entity` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `company_name` (`company_name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS=',\\s*FULLTEXT[^\n]*)' -v ORS= '1' file
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `entity` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Since you are using GNU sed (for `-i`) I assume you will have no problem using GNU awk and if you need inplace editing add `-i inplace` at the start.

Comment: Your script doesn't remove all the FULLTEXT entries from the second sample provided by OP. I'm not sure if that is what OP intended. Also it removes commas from last two lines. I wonder if I am using a different version or awk or something.

Comment: It removes commas from the end of every line that precedes a line containing FULLTEXT like the OP asked for `How can I remove FULLTEXT line from MySQL dump above and comma on the line before` but I see from his second set of input (which I hadn't noticed before) that that might not be what he actually wants. If/when the OP provides a better description of his requirements I'll take another look. Thanks for noticing and letting me know about the issues.

Comment: @blackpen I went ahead and tweaked it to produce the expected output for the 2nd set of input in the question too. idk if it does what he wants but I think it probably does and it produces the output he wants given the posted input.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -vRS=";"  'NF{gsub(/),\n +FULLTEXT.*)/,")\n)",$0);$0=$0";"}1' file
```

Comment: I think the syntax may have got lost in copy pasting (or I may have a different version of awk than yours. It showed syntax error). Just letting you know.

Comment: @blackpen it's not you and it's not your awk version, there are multiple syntax errors in that script.

Comment: sorry, i have  have got lost in copy pasting!